# Graphql : Getting HTTPError : 403 Client error

Tags: python, http, graphql

While parsing GraphQL URL " http://swapi.graphene-python.org/graphql" and trying to get attributes for "**myFavouriteFilm**", experiencing "***requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: http://swapi.graphene-python.org/graphql***" error.

```
from gql import Client, gql
from gql.transport.requests import RequestsHTTPTransport



client = Client(
    transport=RequestsHTTPTransport(url='http://swapi.graphene-python.org/graphql')
)

query = gql('''
 {
  myFavoriteFilm: film(id:"RmlsbToz") {
    id
    title
    episodeId
  }
}
''')

print(client.execute(query))
```

Sometimes, for some other GraphQL query, getting ***requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:726)***
When I try to mention "SSL.verify=False", it throws "***Syntax error***"
So, not able to figure-out, is it something to do with my configuration or coding syntax issue.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to be authorized to perform the query. Nothing is wrong about your query syntax. You may want to investigate the API service if you need to authorize with an API key or session.